# Save UIView's representation to file

Tags: iphone, image, uiview, save

What is the easiest way to save UIView's representation to file?

My solution is,

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(someView.frame.size);
 [someView drawRect:someView.frame];
 UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 NSString* pathToCreate = @"sample.png";

 NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
 [imageData writeToFile:pathToCreate atomically:YES];
```

but it seems tricky, and I think there must be more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can also use the layer like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(someView.bounds.size);
[someView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: I see. It seems better than mine. :)

Comment: And if you want double-resolution on iPhone 4, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions