# need to be able to email a document or a content of UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, attachment

a noob question here.

i would like to give the user a button that would prep an email with the content of a UIView attached.

is this (easily) doable ? I know how to create a basic email, but not with attachments and certainly not with a dump of an UIView content. I am guessing this would be a two step process. First get the content of the UIView into a "attachable form" (how ? #1). Then attach it. (how ? #2)

could someone please point me the right direction ?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can start by converting the UIView to an image.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.bounds.size);
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

after that you can read that to see how to attach the image to the mail

http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/07/how-to-make-your-iphone-app-send-email-with-attachments/

good luck

Comment: thanks for the reply ... I think that I would need to transform the UIImage into a jpg file and save it in the filesystem before being able to attach it.

Comment: found how to save it to a file here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051630/save-uiviews-representation-to-file