# How to save the content of scrollview to photo library in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, photolibrary

I am new to ios development. I am trying to implement an ios application with UIScrollview.
The purpose of my scroll view is to arrange some images. I need to save the content of the scrollview to photo Library, attach it to email, etc.

Is it posible?
If it is possible, how can I do this?

If any body know please clear my doubt. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean `save the scrollview`? very hard to understand...

Comment: i want to save entire Scrollview.

Comment: but why do you want to store scrollview? strange it is..!!

Comment: I want to save the entire content of scrollview to photo library. Is any method for save the contents of scroll view to photo library.

Comment: Please! you want **the content of** scrollview, instead of the *scrollview* itself! Please don't ask strange question like this to confuse us!

Comment: sorry for my error.  I am a beginner in ios

Comment: well @John ,don't worry, i have understand and answered your question.

Comment: Just look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41920416/how-to-make-a-screenshot-of-all-the-content-of-a-scrollview

Comment: It's not your fault. Your question is not strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments, I understand that you want to save the whole content of a `UIScrollView`.

1. Firstly, whenever you use `UIScrollView`, you always have to set another `UIView` as its content. That `UIView` is exactly the **whole content of** your `UIScrollView`.
2. So the question becomes **how to save a `UIView` as an image or attach it into email**, well I find a few pages to you which is exactly what you want.

[Save UIView's representation to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051630/save-uiviews-representation-to-file)
http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/27/1188/
http://cocoatouch.blog138.fc2.com/blog-entry-57.html

Comment: You are so mean

Comment: a scroll view can contain many views, it doesn't just have to contain one view