# How to make a screenshot of all the content of a Scrollview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swift3, screenshot

I want to create a screenshot of a `UIScrollView` which should contain the whole content of the scroll view, even that content, which is currently not visible to the user. For that I tried the following two methods:

```
func snapShot(view:UIView) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, true, 0);

    view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true);

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}

func snapShotScrollView(scrollView:UIScrollView) -> UIImage {
    let bounds = scrollView.bounds;

    scrollView.bounds.size = scrollView.contentSize;

    let image = snapShot(scrollView);

    scrollView.bounds = bounds;

    return image;
}
```

But the resulting image is still just showing those view elements inside the scroll view which are currently visible to the user. But I want to see all views.

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

I also tried:

```
func snapshot() -> UIImage? {
    var image: UIImage?

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scrollView.contentSize)

    let savedContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    let savedFrame = scrollView.frame;

    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero;
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: scrollView.contentSize.height);

    scrollView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
    scrollView.frame = savedFrame;

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image
}
```

**Edit 2**

My `UIScrollView` is placed inside a `UIView` and does contain a `UIStackView`. The View is designed as a popover view so that it looks like a dialogue is popping up. The code sample from my first edit is working in a blank `UIViewController` with only one `UIScrollView` but not in the mentioned constellation.

Comment: I don't think it's easy, as `scrollView` just draws what it needs and is not really tailored to that case.

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539717/getting-a-screenshot-of-a-uiscrollview-including-offscreen-parts

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To Swift from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3539944/1457385), adding a test ViewController:

```
class ScreenShotTestViewController: UIViewController {

    var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: view.frame.size))
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height * 2)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: view.frame.size.height * 1.5, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 44.0))
        label.text = "Hello World!"
        scrollView.addSubview(label)

        let screenShot = snapshot()
    }

    func snapshot() -> UIImage?
    {      
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scrollView.contentSize)

        let savedContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
        let savedFrame = scrollView.frame

        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: scrollView.contentSize.height)

        scrollView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset
        scrollView.frame = savedFrame

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }
}
```

Results in an image of the complete content, including subviews:

[image]

Comment: they key of your solution is to set the UIScrollView width/height to the UIScrollView content width/height even if a part is not visible for the user?

Comment: is it possible to make this screenshot in the background that the user don't see this temporal screenshot view?

Comment: Code is working just fine. You could get rid of the semicolons though.

Comment: You can use 'UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scrollView.contentSize, false, 0.0)' instead. This way the screenshot has better resolution.

Comment: crashing at UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!