# How to insert a UITextView to a UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitextview

I'm programming an application, in wich you create UIImageView-objects. 
The color of these objects can be set.

But the next step I am trying to do is: set a TextView in the imageView, but this text should entered by the user (certainly realized with the class UIKeyboard.)

Im sum: I have a imageView, which needs an editable UITextView in it.

Do you have any idea how it could be realized?

Comment: Wouldn't placing a UITextView on top over your UIImageView solve the problem?

Comment: have you tried `[myUIImageView addSubView:myUITextView]` by chance?

Comment: Tom Jowett thanks, it is working. Just working on optimizing the whole thing :)

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is wrong.

You want an image view because the app lets you "create an image"

In reality and technically this isn't correct, what you will want to be doing is using a simple `UIView` to set he colour of an area, and you an place a `UITextField` or `UITextView` over that.

A `UIImageView` is a very specific `UIView` subclass for displaying images. You can't add your other UI inside of it, the best you could do is over it.

I you do use a `UIView`, when you're done you need to "convert" your `UIView` to an image which you can then use to save, send etc

For more about that check out [Save UIView's representation to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051630/save-uiviews-representation-to-file)

Answer (score 0):

You simply want to subclass UIImageView and add a UITextView during init. Like this

```
@interface MyImageView : UIImageView {   

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextView *textView;
@end
```

And the implementation

```
@implementation MyImageView
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
        [self addSubview:self.textView];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: I really don't suggest subclassing UIImageView here, please see my thoughts below.