# conceptually how to write on an image in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I am just starting conceptually for a **meme-generator** (writing texts on images) 
conceptually like this

[image: Meme Generator]

**But more for an iPhone. what could be the way to achieve this and Draw some text on image
and return an image with text**.

***I need a 1000 foot view of how it will be done. conceptually?***

Comment: UIView which has - UIImageView which draws Image and UILabel to draw Text.

Comment: but how would i get the image from that view? an image with text so that i can post it furthur?

Comment: You should do like `Kashif Zaidi` suggested and after that check http://stackoverflow.com/q/4334233/2315974.

Comment: 1000-foot view? Learn about graphics contexts. http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_graphics_contexts Note that a UIImage knows how to draw itself into a graphics context, and an NSString knows how to draw itself into a graphics context, so you've got it made in the shade.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually:

1. create a UIView
2. add UIImageView(s) to UIView
3. add UITextView(s)  to UIView
4. create ImageRepresentaion Image from UIView

Related: [Save UIView's representation to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051630/save-uiviews-representation-to-file)